# How to enable password for administrator user account

Tags: password, users, administrator

I disabled the password for my user account while I was logged in (I was the only administrator). But I did not enable automatic login. I switched user to "Guest", but when I switched back to my account (the administrator account), my user account askes me for my password. When I type my password in, it says its incorrect. So I need a way of accessing my user account if this is the case.